# Use a list in prepared statement

Tags: python, list, set, prepared-statement, psycopg2

I want to use a Python `list` (or a `set` actually) in my `execute`, but I don't quite get it.

```
BRANDS = {
  'toyota',
  'ford',
  'dodge',
  'spyker'
}

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT model FROM cars WHERE brand IN (%s)", (list(BRANDS),)
```

How can I use a `set` or `list` in an `IN` clause in psycopg2?

Comment: Try `tuple(BRANDS)`

Comment: @IonutTicus No. Same error.

Comment: No, using `+` or `%` for queries is [BAD](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters).

Comment: @IonutTicus I think you replied in the wrong subthread and meant to reply to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60884175/8182118

Comment: @Masklinn: there was a comment by someone who suggested using **%** but it got deleted it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psycopg2 converts lists to *arrays*, and `(%s)` means a single value inside a tuple, so that's obviously not correct.

What you want to do is either:

- let postgres convert a tuple to a tuple

  ```py
  cur.execute("SELECT model FROM cars WHERE brand IN %s", (tuple(BRANDS),))
  ```
- use array operators with an array

  ```py
  cur.execute("SELECT model FROM cars WHERE brand = any(%s)", (list(BRANDS),))
  ```

The performances should be equivalent, I usually recommend `=any()` because the typing makes more sense *and it works even if the parameter is empty*, postgres does *not* like empty tuples so `brand in ()` generates an error. `brand = any('{}')` however works fine.

Oh and psycogp2's `execute` is completely happy with a *list* of parameters, I find that much more readable and less error prone so I'd recommend it:

```py
cur.execute(
    "SELECT model FROM cars WHERE brand = any(%s)", [
    list(BRANDS)
])
```

Comment: Thanks. The `tuple` and leaving the parentheses after `IN` fixed it.

Comment: @BartFriederichs sure